# Pandas divide multiple columns based on its max value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with 40 columns where some columns are binary columns containing only 0 or 1. I want to divide all non-binary columns with a column called 'size'

Right now I am using:

```
for i in range(df.shape[1]):
    col = df.iloc[:, i]
    if int(col.max()) > 1: # to check whether this column is binary
        df.iloc[:, i] = col/df['size']
    i+=1
```

I feel that we should avoid using foor-loop in pandas, so is there a more elegant way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO `numpy` and `tolist` is not needed here, pandas has everything for this task:

return all columns with maximum values >1 and throw 'size' away:

```
cols = df.columns[df.max()>1].drop('size')
```

and for the calculation, only full columns are chosen, no subsets, so you can leave 'ix' or 'loc' away and index directly by column names:

```
df[cols] = df[cols].div(df['size'], 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like the following should work (assuming that there is at least one non-binary column in the dataframe):

```
cols = df.columns[np.where(df.max(axis=0)>1)[0]].tolist() # find all non-binary column names
cols.remove('size') # exclude the column 'size' from the list, assuming that size is a non-binary column as well
df.loc[:,cols] = df.loc[:,cols].div(df.size, axis=0) # divide all the non-binary columns by size
#df.head()
```

Comment: `ix` has been deprecated since v0.20, use `.loc` instead.